# dompdf->render(); not working in api class

Tags: php, html, class, pdf, dompdf

I'm having a problem when trying to render html to pdf using dompdf.

I have the code placed inside a class and after the procedure code I would like it to create a pdf of the html.

This is the code I have at the moment:

```
$templatefile = file_get_contents("templates/costreport.htm");
//fill headers
$templatefile = str_replace("%DATES%",stripslashes($startdate)." - ".stripslashes($enddate),$templatefile);     

if ($siteid>0) {
    $pdfname = "costreport-".$clientid.".pdf";
} else {
    $pdfname = "costreport-".$clientid."-".$siteid.".pdf";
}
//insert into database
//Close and output PDF document
$pdfname = str_replace("/","-",$pdfname);
$pdfname = str_replace("\\","-",$pdfname);
//create pdf
// unregister Yii's autoloader
spl_autoload_unregister('my_autoloader');
// register dompdf's autoloader
require_once("../system/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");
// register Yii's autoloader again
spl_autoload_register('my_autoloader');
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->set_paper("A4","portrait");
$dompdf->load_html($templatefile);
//set_time_limit(240);
$dompdf->render();
$pdf = $dompdf->output();
// You can now write $pdf to disk, store it in a database or stream it
// to the folder.
file_put_contents('../tmp/'.$clientid.'/'.$pdfname, $pdf);
```

The code fails when the dompdf->render(); is in but once I take that line out the code works and the file is created but I cant open it if it hasn't rendered.

I've tried debugging the code and made the template is HTML valid but I'm at a loss now.

The error I am getting back is just `boolen false` when I run the script with the `dompdf->render();` in it.

Comment: Can you include the error you get in your question?

Comment: I've added the error in the question :)

Comment: Have you tried a simple HTML document (e.g. `<p>Hello World!</p>`)? If that works then maybe it's something about your template. You might try enabling error reporting.

Comment: yeah still getting boolen false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had this piece of code at the top of my class.

```
/set up path to new dir including dir to be created
            chdir("../tmp/");
            $newdirpath = getcwd()."/".$clientid;
            //if an old invoice ticket pack exists unlink it so as not to get things confused with the new pack being created.
            if (file_exists(getcwd()."/$clientid_$siteid_CostReport.pdf")) {
                unlink(getcwd()."/$clientid_$siteid_CostReport.pdf");
            }
            //setup temp dir
            if (!is_dir($newdirpath)) {
                //create new dir if it doesn't already exist!
                mkdir($newdirpath);
            } else {
                //dir already exists we need to empty it out first incase there's old stuff in there we don't want to duplicate data
                //$this->removedirectory($newdirpath,false);
            }
```